# Как найти минимальный элемент главной диагонали двумерного массива?

Tags: c#

```
int[,] myMatrix = new int[8, 8];
Random rand = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < myMatrix.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < myMatrix.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        myMatrix[i, j] = rand.Next(0, 100);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Диагональ матрицы это по сути обычный одномерный массив под углом, мы можем пройтись по нему с помощью 1-го цикла просто меняя одновременно строку и столбец

```
// вывод главной диагонали
for (int row = 0, column = 0; row < myMatrix.GetLength(0); row++, column++)
{
   Console.Write($"{myMatrix[row, column]} ");
}
```

Для квадратной матрицы можно упростить до следующего вида:

```
for (int i= 0; i < myMatrix.GetLength(0); i++)
{
   Console.Write($"{myMatrix[i, i]} ");
}
```

Ну а найти минимум одномерного массива, я надеюсь, для вас не составит никакого труда)

Comment: int minValue = myMatrix[0, 0]; for (int i = 1; i < myMatrix.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                if (myMatrix[i, i] < minValue)
                {
                    minValue = myMatrix[i, i];
                }
            }    примерно так получиться?

Comment: @Ann да, всё верно